# How do I use a Microsoft Account when setting up Windows 10 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

I am re-installing Windows 10 Enterprise onto my home computer.  It is asking me for a work or school account instead of a Microsoft Account.  How do I sign in with my Microsoft Account instead of my work account?  The only option I see is to "Domain join instead"

I previously installed Windows 10 Enterprise and used my Microsoft Account, but I can't remember how.  Do I need a local account first and then add a Microsoft Account?  I just can't seem to find the option to use a Microsoft Account, only work-or-school account or local user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here (quite certain) is to set up the computer with a local Account. Make sure it is running properly. Make sure the User Profile is named as you wish.

Now convert the local account to a Microsoft Account.

I have done this before on Windows 10 Pro machines and it works fine.